# Disable auto discover of include paths in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a self contained project where every included file is within the project itself.
In the project `properties -> "C/C++ General" -> "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." -> "Providers"` I disabled the entries I don't need, but something re-enables the `"CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings"`.
Is there a way to **permanently disable this option?**
I want to keep the indexer working, and also I have some entries in the `CDT` managed build entries so its not an option to get rid of the build configuration `(I do not build/start the build of the project from Eclipse).`
The automatically added includes conflicts with the files within my project messing up the indexer `(it adds the MinGW includes)`.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 7.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution, but if you can't figure out what is re-enabling the built-in compiler settings provider, you can make it be effectively a no-op by modifying the "Command to get compiler specs" to something that doesn't output the includes. (Removing the `-v` flag should do it. If you also don't want the compiler's built-in macro definitions, remove the `-dD` flag as well.)

Comment: Already tried that, it also restores the command. If I look into the .cproject/.project files the new command does not get stored there.

Comment: The command gets stored in `.settings/language.settings.xml`. I'm not sure what is overwriting / restoring it, but I'm pretty sure that's your problem. Perhaps prefs synchronization / Oomph related? (See e.g. [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507132)).

Comment: Oomph is not configured. For now I changed the command then made the `.settings/language.settings.xml` write protected. I also don't know what triggers the restore. It happens when I re-build the indexer, refresh, close, open the project / eclipse but not all the time. It only happens like 1 in 10 times.

Comment: Hey @VKocsis, have you managed to figure this out? I suspect I'm running into the same issue here. In my case, the result is a bit more benign, since the include paths Eclipse is automatically generating don't actually contain any archives, so my projects aren't accidentally picking up the wrong archives. But it's still frustrating because I'd like to keep my build settings from getting polluted with wrong/auto-generated paths; it might confused other devs.